# 10 similar quadrilaterals with 8 points.

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, polygons, constraints, constants

Let 8 points define 10 or more similar quadrilaterals with no self-mapping.  No self-mapping means that a square counts just once instead of 8 times.  What is the maximal number of differently sized similar quadrilaterals in a solution? I think the answer is 5 different sizes.

$\{ \\
\ \ \ \ \{7,3,4,2\}, \{1,2,8,3\}, \\
\ \ \ \ \{2,3,1,4\}, \{3,2,7,8\}, \\
\ \ \ \ \{3,4,2,5\}, \{2,8,3,6\},\\
\ \ \ \  \{3,1,4,6\}, \{2,7,8,5\},\\
\ \ \ \ \{4,2,5,6\}, \{8,3,6,5\} \\
\}
$

[image: Plastic 8]

For the points, pick the positive complex root of $x^3-x-1=0$.  Powers -1 to 3 give points 1 to 5. Point 6 is the origin. The small numbers give the distance in terms of powers of the square root of the [plastic constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html).

I know there are other solutions based on adding/using points to regular n-gons.  I think an asymmetric quadrilateral from the octagon gives the most similar quadrilaterals, 16 with 8 points. **What is the maximum number of similar quadrilaterals for $n$ points?**  I think the solution will initially be $2 n$. At 16 points, this method gives 38 similar polygons, shown below with lines and colored splines. I don't know if 38 similar polygons from 16 points is maximal.
[image] [image]

Comment: Point 6 is the origin. For points 7 and 8, rotate points 1 and 4 around the midpoint of 2-3. I came up with the question when I noticed how many similar quadrilaterals were in this point set.

Comment: points 1 to 8 are {{-0.877439,-0.744862}, {1,0}, {-0.662359,0.56228}, {0.122561,-0.744862}, {0.337641,0.56228}, {0,0}, {1.21508,1.30714}, {0.21508,1.30714}}

Comment: You have given the same coordinates for points [7] and [8] although they are visibly different points. Is point [7] obtained in a different way (not as power of $P$ with my notations) ?

Comment: Point 8 + {1,0}  gives point 7

Comment: I used my RhoQuad substitution tiling system, https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SubstitutionTilings/  or https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1679969

Answer (score 1):

Here is a principle yielding an easy counting method.

Let $P=-0.662359+0.56228i$ (one of the roots of $x^3-x-1=0$).

As I understand it, your points are, in the order $1,2... 8$:

$$P^{-1}, \ \ 1, \ \ P, \ \ P^2, \ \ P^3=P+1, \ \ 0, \ \ 1+P^{-2}, \ \ P^{-2}$$

(Edit: the two last ones have been corrected)

With these notations, it is rather easy to look for similar quadrilaterals  $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. For example these ones:

$$P*\underbrace{[P^{-2},P^{-1},1,P]}_{Q_1}=\underbrace{[P^{-1},1,P,P^2]}_{Q_2}$$

by the very fact that **multiplying by a complex number amounts to a similitude**.

In a reciprocal way, it looks a reasonable assumption that all similitudes are obtained in this way.

Remark: A special category of quadrilaterals are those with (invariant) point $0$ (origin). They will provide similar quadrilaterals by looking for similar triangles (with the other vertices). For example:

$$P*\underbrace{[P^{-2},P^{-1},1,0]}_{Q_1}=\underbrace{[P^{-1},1,P,0]}_{Q_2}$$

Comment: Point 8 is P^(-2).  Point 7 doesn't seem to be a simple power.

Comment: I have added this sentence: "In a reciprocal way, it looks a reasonable assumption that all similitudes are obtained in this way."

Comment: The more I see your second figure, the more a 3D interpretation looks desirable...